# Nodejs selenium process closes after opening page

Tags: node.js, selenium

When running selenium i get the message

```
 DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12963/devtools/browser/409ca9c9-8325-45be-9443-2c33bba4be7d
```

A page opens with the requested URL, but the process closes on the terminal.
How can i make it so that it keeps running?

I have little code and am new to this. Here's what i have.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```

EDIT:

I'm using chromedriver 2.26

Comment: did it open google.com ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes, is it supposed to close? If so, how do i prevent this?

Comment: put some sleep after `driver.get()`, the window shall stand correctly

Comment: "using chromedriver 2.26" Why so far outdated?This is not going to work with any browser from past few years!